# W 8.1 upgrade to windows 10, how to recover recycle bin?

Tags: windows-8

A file was placed in recycle bin on w 8.1, then I upgraded to windows 10. Now I want to restore that file.

I have an windows.old file.

How do I do this?

Thank you

Comment: You don't; The file is gone; the file no longer exists, and does is not exist in Windows.old